# Adverb for a third of a year

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Similar to [Is there a proper term to describe 1/3 of a year (4 months)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23262/is-there-a-proper-term-to-describe-1-3-of-a-year-4-months)

Are there any words to describe a trimester as an adverb? The only one I've seen is *triannually* (in the link above) which is a bit verbose in my opinion.

Comment: One uses a prepositional phrase for this. That’s what language is about, you know: stringing bits together using syntax.

Comment: This is to complement words like annually, quarterly, ...

Comment: I think there isn't a more concise term simply because it doesn't come up very much. Not many activities are triannual.

Comment: @Barmar The very first time you get in trouble for making semimonthly payments instead of biweekly ones is when you realize that writing "every X units" or "Y times per Z unit" is infinitely preferable for clearly conveying meaning of non-unitary periodicities. :)

Comment: @tchrist Indeed, there are probably lots of people who don't know the difference between _biennial_ and _biannual_.

Comment: *trimesterly* -- but such a word is confusing (e.g., 3 months or 4?).